# File permission set to 755 but still no web access

Tags: unix, centos

I've ran into a problem after setting a folder and its contents to 755 permissions. 
I ran

```
chmod 755 -R folder/
```

However, when trying to access in my /var/www folder via the browser I get a 403 Forbidden error. 
I did download the folder from the web, but other files with 755 permissions are loaded just fine into the browser. Here is what it looks like:

```
ls -l
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root 4096 folder
```

Edit: If you're going to down vote, how about explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
drwxr-xr-x.
```

The trailing dot means the directory has an SElinux ACL, which is likely the cause of your problem. -- the ACL denies access.